# Extract Twitter username with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

Say, I have a direct URL to a Twitter post, like

```
$url="http://twitter.com/#!/YourName/status/01234567890123456";
```

or

```
$url="http://twitter.com/YourName/status/01234567890123456";
```

Could you please advise the simplest way in PHP (regexp, i suppose) to extract YourName out of these strings that looks something like that:

```
$account= ??? (???,$url);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do this.

Something along the lines of:

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/twitter.com\/(#!\/)?([^\/]*)/", $url, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I have created a rubular here: http://rubular.com/r/YNw7PVSxqS

Comment: You should modify this for https. Maybe this will work `/http(s):\/\/twitter.com\/(#!\/)?([^\/]*)/`